# Jenkins + Sonar: ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project does not pass the quality gate

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am trying to integrate Sonar in Jenkins. Due to some bad code quality - it is giving below error.

> "ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution 
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project does not pass the quality
>   gate."

I do not have permission to change the quality gate right now. I want to make the build success irrespective of quality gate result. How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Seems that you have installed https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker So either uninstall it, either try to set `sonar.buildbreaker.skip=true`. Also note that SonarQube developers do not recommend to break the build - http://www.sonarqube.org/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is correct but I don't have access to the settings. Also, I didn't want to change global policies or server settings even if I had the access.
Luckily I can modify the script that runs the scanner. In the begin command (whatever method you are using to execute the begin command) add the flag to skip the build breaker.

sonar.buildbreaker.skip=true

Normally it is added in the form of:

/dLsonar.buildbreaker.skip=true